# How to get different colour for each legend in a bar chart

Tags: grafana

Grafana version : 9.2.4
Bar graph that I created has
[same colour for each legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eRoD.png)

I want to have different colour for each legend.
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55fFP.png)
How to achieve this on grafana dashboard UI

Answer (score 2):

Define some "overides" properties for fields a to e. Define for each field ("fields with name") "standard options > color scheme" -> single color and chose the color you wish in the right.

Good luck.
Alexander

Answer (score 1):

For my side, i have chose

Visualizations---Bar Chart---Add filed overide--Fields with name---"Your Column"---Add override Property---Standard options---Color scheme----"Blue-Yellow-RED(by value)"
Example:

[image]

FYI:
https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-get-different-colour-for-each-legend-in-a-bar-chart/82751/5